# MySQL LIKE returning all the result

Tags: php, mysql, search, pdo

I am trying to filter result based on a string that comes from the form. This is my code.

```
<?php
    $query = $_GET['query']; // gets the string entered from the form.

    $userSearch = $db->prepare("SELECT id, user_id, feedback FROM `QComments` 
                                WHERE `feedback` 
                                LIKE '%$query%' 
                                ORDER BY user_id");

    $userSearch->execute();
    $userSearchResult = $userSearch->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
?>

<?php // Display search result

    foreach ($userSearchResult as $result1){
        echo $result1['feedback']; 
    }

?>
```

This basically display all the record form the database no matter what the string I enter.

But when I enter this MySQL statement in PHPMYAdmin SQL box

```
SELECT id, user_id, feedback FROM `QComments` 
WHERE `feedback` 
LIKE '%suggestion%' 
ORDER BY user_id
```

I only gets the result that has suggestion keyword. But the PHP is displaying everything. What is wrong with my code? Please suggest me.

Comment: If you echo `$query` does it have the correct value? You aren't using prepared statements correctly, http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php.

Comment: first check what is preparing by your prepare....it is same what query you want or like '%%'...

Answer (score 1):

Using prepared statements like this has always worked for me.

Prepared statements don't simply do a string-replace. They transport the data completely separate from the query. Quotes are only needed when embedding values into a query

```
<?php
    $query = '%'.$_GET['query'].'%'; // gets the string entered from the form.

    $userSearch = $db->prepare("SELECT id, user_id, feedback FROM `QComments` 
                                WHERE `feedback` 
                                LIKE :query
                                ORDER BY user_id");
    $userSearch->BindParam(':query', $query);
    $userSearch->execute();
    $userSearchResult = $userSearch->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
?>
```